# Can you kill Midi-chlorians?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, midichlorians

Could you kill the Midi-chlorians in someone to make them lose their Force sensitivity?

Comment: Midi-chlorians don't give you Force. You get Midi-chlorians if you have the Force. More Force, more Midi-chlorians, not the other way around.

Comment: @Valorum Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast - The problem is that they've been portrayed inconsistently. One answer isn't gonna cut it

Comment: All living creatures have Midi-chlorians and they are believed to be essential for life. Force users have higher concentrations of them. Killing the Midi-chlorians would most likely also kill the individual as well

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: Midi-chlorians are explicitly stated to be symbionts living within the cells of all living things (rather like real-world mitochondria.) Symbionts by their very nature perform vital functions that the host cannot do themselves. So if one were to damage and kill all of the trillions of micro-cellular symbionts inside a lifeform, it's cells would cease to function and the lifeform will expire.

That's even assuming it's possible to kill them at all without also killing the host cells anyway, which is highly dubious at best. So any attempt to "strip" the ability to use the force in this manner would be biologically lethal, and thus making said being one with the cosmic force at the moment of death.

Comment: I don't think this sentence is correct: "Symbionts by their very nature perform vital functions that the host cannot do themselves." [Symbiosis, as described by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiosis) can be "mutualistic" (both benefit), "commensalistic" (one benefits, the other is neutral), or "parasitic" (one benefits, the other suffers); and also either "obligatory" (required for life) or "facultative" (useful but not necessary), on one or both sides. A real-life example: we have many *facultative* bacteria living in our guts; killing them is detrimental, but not directly fatal.

Comment: @IMSoP Either way the point remains; anything you do to a lifeform that'd kill ALL of the mitochondria in it's cells, would also kill those cells and the lifeform, whether directly or otherwise.

Comment: Again, not *necessarily* true. Taking the gut flora example again, we can take antibiotics that kill bacteria, and they don't kill us. You could conceivably have some poison that entered individual cells, and made them unsuitable for midi-chlorians, without affecting the rest of the cellular machinery. It's quite *plausible* that they would be bound up with life processes in a way that makes that impossible, but it doesn't follow straightforwardly from a statement that they are symbionts, it needs some additional supporting lore about what *kind* of symbionts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In Legacy, Palpatine absorbs midi-chlorians from others, which gives him power temporarily, but the midi-chlorians die as they are not adapted to him.